# Is a generalization of Vandermonde matrix with factorials invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Is this matrix invertible?

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a_1 & \frac{a_1^2}{2!} & \dots & \frac{a_1^m}{m!}\\
1 & a_2 & \frac{a_2^2}{2!} & \dots & \frac{a_2^m}{m!}\\
\vdots &{ } & \vdots &{ } & \vdots\\ 
1 & a_m & \frac{a_m^2}{2!} & \dots & \frac{a_m^m}{m!}
\end{bmatrix}$

This matrix is closely related to the Vandermonde matrix but I don't know if/how I can use this fact to show that this matrix is invertible.

Comment: What do you know about the behavior of a determinant when you scale a column by a number?

Comment: Do you know that the vandermonde matrix is invertible?

Comment: @darijgrinberg If $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix, we have $\det(A) = 1/(2!3!\dots m!) \det(V)$ so the determinant is non-zero!

Comment: Expand it along last column and use induction may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hint provided by @darij-grinberg:

If $$ is the Vandermonde matrix, we have

$\det()=1/(2!3!…!)\det()$

so the determinant of $A$ is non-zero.